# Capturing logged-in-user details from active session in other websites

Tags: facebook, python-2.7, web, session-cookies

I want to track the user traffic on my website. Although I have all the tracking tools on it, i want to be able to capture more information about the visitor. Is it possible that if the user is logged to Google/Facebook, I can capture his username or ID from the respective cookies?

I am using Python web framework.

Answer (score 0):

## No

The browser does not send cookies for other domains.